# Why different java versions from terminal/IDE?

Tags: java, environment-variables

I am getting Gradle build errors and my theory is, it's because of the JDK version I'm using. My JAVA_HOME is set to JDK 8 and the command prompt reflects this:
[image]

If I run git bash terminal from my STS4 IDE, it returns JDK 17:[image]

How is this possible? Yes, I have my environment variables pointing to JDK 8 ( this is the desired version) and the path is listed FIRST. For some reason, my IDE is picking up version 17. Lastly, yes I have reopened my IDE/command prompt since making these changes.

Any ideas/explanations would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can change JDK from your ide setting

Comment: See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756951/how-do-i-change-the-java-version-fro-sts4)

Comment: Do you have a `~/.bash_profile` in your git bash ?